# How to place equation number below formula?

Tags: equations, subequations

I have 3 matrices and I want them to be in one row, with a reference number below each matrix. How do I get the equation number below a formula? (similar to subfigure)

From the comments:
- I want to reference the equations via \ref
- The subequation tag was that because I have the impression that it could work like subfigure, but I could not see a way so far

Comment: Do these equation numbers need to be accessible by way of the `\ref` macro?

Comment: You've set the `subequations` tag. Does this mean that you're using a `subequations` environment for the three equations? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a tabular (or better tabularx) environment, or in minipages.
And do the equation number handling yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\makeeqno{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{CCC}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{pmatrix}$
&
    $\begin{pmatrix}
      11 & 12 \\ 21 & 22
    \end{pmatrix}$
&
  $\begin{pmatrix}
    A & B \\ C & D
  \end{pmatrix}$
  \\
  \makeeqno \label{first} & \makeeqno \label{second} &\makeeqno \label{third}\\
\end{tabularx}

Now refer to equation \ref{first} and equation \ref{third}.

Another equation:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
      E = m c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or with minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\makeeqno{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\newenvironment{mip}{
  \begin{minipage}{3cm}\begin{center}}{\end{center}\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mip}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{pmatrix}$\\
  \makeeqno \label{first}
\end{mip}
 \begin{mip}
    $\begin{pmatrix}
      11 & 12 \\ 21 & 22
    \end{pmatrix}$\\
    \makeeqno \label{second}
  \end{mip}
  \begin{mip}
  $\begin{pmatrix}
    A & B \\ C & D
  \end{pmatrix}$\\
    \makeeqno \label{third}
\end{mip}

Now refer to equation \ref{first} and equation \ref{third}.

Another equation:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
      E = m c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing an environment to do this seems tricky as I can't think of a nice syntax that caters for both the "column" entries and the labels for the corresponding equation numbers (this is not to say that this is not possible only that I didn't think of a way:).

Here is a way to do want you want "by hand": the matrices are put into an `array` environment and then the equation numbers are added below them using a macro `\addlabel`. This macro takes one argument, the label name, and then increments and prints the `equation` number and adds the `\label`. Since you mention `subeqations` I assume that you are using the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Here is the output:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addlabel[1]{% using \label causes spurious so use \ltx@label
  \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\ltx@label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
      & \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
      & \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
      \\[1mm]% add some extra space after the equation line
      % now add labels to matrices
      \addlabel{one} &  & \addlabel{three}
    \end{array}
  \]

  See equations \ref{one} and \ref{three}.
\end{document}
```

I have left out an equation number for the second matrix only to show that this is possible.

The definition of `\addlabel` is more convoluted than you might expect because it calls `\ltx@label`. This is because [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) redefines `\label` so that it can check for various errors, including having more than one label or the same equation, so we get warnings if we try to use `\label`. In fact, `\ltx@label` is the "real" latex `\label` command, so we can avoid the amsmath warnings by using it.